# control textbox disable or readme behavior with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to lock/unlock a  series of textboxes with one checkbox
by default they are all locked
I tried using the disable feature and using javascript to lock them however text boxes do not submit a value on a disabled field. I need these textboxes to submit a value regardless of if they are locked or unlocked

I was using

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status;
document.f1.shopper_pay.disabled = status;
document.f1.shopper_reimb.disabled = status;
document.f1.Shop_cost.disabled = status;
}
//-->
</script>
```

with

```
<form name='f1' action='editsurvey.php' method='post'>
<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" >
<input type='text' name='shopper_pay' value=$0.00 disabled='disabled'>
<input type='text' name='shopper_reimb' value=$40.00 disabled='disabled'>
<input type='text' name='Shop_cost' value=$35.00 disabled='disabled'>
```

unfortunately functionally this works but when submitting it does not include the disabled fields - Anyone have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `DOM` with `Disabled` attribute will not submitted or you can say their values will not posted.

You can post it by Simply change `disabled` to `readonly`

If you're using `jQuery` then remove the `disabled` attribute when submitting the form:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("input").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put hidden form fields .Copy the values before disabled.